# How i get value from future in dart and store to global varible

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

i am assign the variable class level variable from future response but it will return null

```
getRequest(urlPath).then((value) => {response = value.data.toString()});
```

where response is class level varable **value** is having data but still response is null

```
Future<Response> getRequest(String url) async {
return await m_basicDioConnection.getConnection().get(url);
```

}

HttpService class

```
class HttpService {
BasicDioConnection m_basicDioConnection;
HttpService() {
m_basicDioConnection = new BasicDioConnection();
}

Future<Response> getRequest(String url) async {
return await m_basicDioConnection.getConnection().get(url);
}

Future<Response> postRequest(String url, String data) async {
return await m_basicDioConnection.getConnection().post(url, data: data);
}

Future<Response> putRequest(String url, String data) async {
return await m_basicDioConnection.getConnection().put(url, data: data);
}
}



class HttpServiceHandler extends HttpService {
String m_response;

set response(String resp) {
 this.m_response = resp;
}

String get response {
 return m_response;
}

String handleRequest(RequestEnumType method, String urlPath, String data) {
String resp;
switch (method) {
  case RequestEnumType.GET:
    getRequest(urlPath)
        .then((value) => {this.response = value.data.toString()});
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.POST:
    postRequest(urlPath, data)
        .then((value) => {this.response = value.data.toString()});
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.PUT:
    putRequest(urlPath, data)
        .then((value) => {this.response = value.data.toString()});
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.DELETE:
    break;
}
print(this.m_response);
return this.response;
```

}
}

Main function

```
void main() {

HttpServiceHandler service = HttpServiceHandler();
String res = service.handleRequest(RequestEnumType.POST, "/api/users",
  "{\"name\":\"hello\",\"job\":\"cenaCenacena\"}");
print(res);
}
```

**print(res);** print null

Comment: did you make sure youre getting the body of your request? do you work with async and are you awaiting your result? Give it a try

Comment: i debug it the values has data but i cant able to assign to class variable

Comment: Please post the whole code. It will make it more clear.

Comment: i post it please suggest me something

Answer (score 0):

Changing your `handleRequest` method should work.

```dart
Future<String> handleRequest(RequestEnumType method, String urlPath, String data) {
String resp;
switch (method) {
  case RequestEnumType.GET:
    resp = await getRequest(urlPath);
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.POST:
    resp = await postRequest(urlPath, data);
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.PUT:
    resp = await putRequest(urlPath, data);
    break;
  case RequestEnumType.DELETE:
    break;
}
this.response = resp.data.toString();
print(this.m_response);
return this.response;
}
```

Also you need to change this part like below:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {

HttpServiceHandler service = HttpServiceHandler();
String res = await service.handleRequest(RequestEnumType.POST, "/api/users",
  "{\"name\":\"hello\",\"job\":\"cenaCenacena\"}");
print(res);
}
```

Comment: i want to to extract data from response without using future and then

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you explain more? You are using `then` in your own code; Where am I using `then`?